# code completion with clang gives wrong results

Tags: vim, autocomplete, clang, vim-plugin

Consider the file `foo.c`:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

int six, bo;
int main(void) {
    return six + b + sizeof(int);
}
```

Then `clang` can be used to suggest possible code completions in line 15 column 19 (portion after the `b` in the `return` statement) as follows:

```
cat foo.c | clang -fsyntax-only -Xclang -code-completion-macros -Xclang  -code-completion-at=-:5:19 -xc -
```

This gives

```
PREFERRED-TYPE: int
COMPLETION: bo : [#int#]bo
COMPLETION: bool : bool
```

Obviously the only right match would be `bo` as an expression is expected.

Does `clang` provide options so that completions that do not lead to an expression are automatically filtered out? Or needs this done manually?

Also, I could not really find any sources that document options for `clang` like `-code-completion-macros` or `-code-completion-at`. The command above which uses these option is used in the [vim-clang](https://github.com/justmao945/vim-clang) plugin. Are these documented somewhere (in hope there are further options).